# how to Scan qr code after capturing an image in react native

Tags: react-native, qr-code

I am making a qr code scanner, where user can upload a qr code image from gallery and from that we can get the data of qr code.

Below is my code:

```
import RNQRGenerator from 'rn-qr-generator';
import {launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';

const options = {
  title: 'photoUpload',
  takePhotoButtonTitle: 'photoTake',
  chooseFromLibraryButtonTitle: 'photoLibrary',
  cancelButtonTitle: 'cancel',
  quality: 0.7,
  base64: true,
  maxWidth: 728,
};
const App = () => {
  const onPick = () => {
    launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        RNQRGenerator.detect({uri: response.assets[0].uri})
          .then(res => {
            console.log('Detected value', res);
            if (res.values.length === 0) {
              console.log('Code not found');
            } else {
              console.log('value: ', res.values);
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('Cannot detect', err);
          });
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <Button
      title="Pick from library"
      onPress={() => {
        onPick();
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

This is working fine if user has the actual qr code image

I have an edge case: if user clicks an image of qr code, and then upload this image from gallery.

For this edge case, my written code is not working. I am not sure how to solve this edge case issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
import RNQRGenerator from 'rn-qr-generator';

RNQRGenerator.detect({
  uri: PATH_TO_IMAGE, // local path of the image. Can be skipped if base64 is passed.
  base64: imageBase64String, // If uri is passed this option will be skipped.
})
  .then(response => {
    const { values } = response; // Array of detected QR code values. Empty if nothing found.
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('Cannot detect QR code in image', error));
```

Comment: I am using this same package. but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

To scan the image and get the information about that image barcode and qrcode...
you have to install `npm i rn-qr-generator` and to choose the image you have to install `npm i react-native-image-picker`

example:-

```
    import {launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';
    import RNQRGenerator from 'rn-qr-generator';
        
  const openlibrary=async()=>{
  const galleryOptions = {
    mediaType: 'photo',
    includeBase64: true,
  };
 launchImageLibrary(galleryOptions,(res)=>{
  
if(res.didCancel){
  console.error("cancelled")
}else{
  RNQRGenerator.detect({
    base64:res?.assets[0]?.base64 
  }).then((item)=>{
    console.log(item)
  }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
  })

}

console.log(res)
   

}).catch(err=>{
  console.log("err",err)
})
```

}

Comment: Can we use Camera as well? Right now I am using import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera'; for Camera Scanning.